# Проблема с CLion, Makefile

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, clion

При попытки собрать проект, я поучаю следующую ошибку

```
mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target 'A3'.  Stop.
```

При этом в Code::blocs проект собирается нормально.
В чем может быть проблема?

Проблема где-то в Makefile

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "MinGW Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.7

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:
```

#=============================================================================
       # Special targets provided by cmake.

```
# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


 # Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
 SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force
```

#=============================================================================
    # Set environment variables for the build.

```
SHELL = cmd.exe

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = "K:\CLion 2016.3.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe"

# The command to remove a file.
RM = "K:\CLion 2016.3.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f

# Escaping for special characters.
EQUALS = =

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = I:\C++\A3

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = I:\C++\A3\cmake-build-debug
```

#=============================================================================
    # Targets provided globally by CMake.

```
# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running 
CMake to regenerate build system..."
    "K:\CLion 2016.3.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -
 B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache

.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

 # Special rule for the target edit_cache
     edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "No
```

interactive CMake dialog available..."
        "K:\CLion 2016.3.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E echo "No interactive CMake dialog available."
    .PHONY : edit_cache

```
 # Special rule for the target edit_cache
 edit_cache/fast: edit_cache

 .PHONY : edit_cache/fast

 # The main all target
 all: cmake_check_build_system
     $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start I:\C++\A3\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles I:\C++\A3\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start I:\C++\A3\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles 0
  .PHONY : all

 # The main clean target
 clean:
     $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 clean
 .PHONY : clean

 # The main clean target
 clean/fast: clean

 .PHONY : clean/fast

 # Prepare targets for installation.
 preinstall: all
     $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 preinstall
    .PHONY : preinstall

   # Prepare targets for installation.
   preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 preinstall
   .PHONY : preinstall/fast

   # clear depends
   depend:
     $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 1
   .PHONY : depend


 #=============================================================================
     # Target rules for targets named A3

      # Build rule for target.
      A3: cmake_check_build_system
      $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 A3
  .PHONY : A3

  # fast build rule for target.
 A3/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/A3.dir/build
  .PHONY : A3/fast

  CompositeShape.obj: CompositeShape.cpp.obj

  .PHONY : CompositeShape.obj

  # target to build an object file
  CompositeShape.cpp.obj:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
  CMakeFiles/A3.dir/CompositeShape.cpp.obj
  .PHONY : CompositeShape.cpp.obj

   CompositeShape.i: CompositeShape.cpp.i

  .PHONY : CompositeShape.i

  # target to preprocess a source file
  CompositeShape.cpp.i:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
 CMakeFiles/A3.dir/CompositeShape.cpp.i
 .PHONY : CompositeShape.cpp.i

 CompositeShape.s: CompositeShape.cpp.s

  .PHONY : CompositeShape.s

  # target to generate assembly for a file
  CompositeShape.cpp.s:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
  CMakeFiles/A3.dir/CompositeShape.cpp.s
  .PHONY : CompositeShape.cpp.s

  circle.obj: circle.cpp.obj

  .PHONY : circle.obj

   # target to build an object file
   circle.cpp.obj:
     $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
  CMakeFiles/A3.dir/circle.cpp.obj
   .PHONY : circle.cpp.obj

   circle.i: circle.cpp.i

   .PHONY : circle.i

   # target to preprocess a source file
   circle.cpp.i:
      $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/A3.dir/circle.cpp.i
   .PHONY : circle.cpp.i

   circle.s: circle.cpp.s

   .PHONY : circle.s

   # target to generate assembly for a file
   circle.cpp.s:
   $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/A3.dir/circle.cpp.s
   .PHONY : circle.cpp.s

    main.obj: main.cpp.obj

   .PHONY : main.obj

    # target to build an object file
    main.cpp.obj:
     $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/A3.dir/main.cpp.obj
      .PHONY : main.cpp.obj

      main.i: main.cpp.i

      .PHONY : main.i

     # target to preprocess a source file
     main.cpp.i:
     $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/A3.dir/main.cpp.i
     .PHONY : main.cpp.i

       main.s: main.cpp.s

       .PHONY : main.s

         # target to generate assembly for a file
   main.cpp.s:
         $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
  CMakeFiles/A3.dir/main.cpp.s
      .PHONY : main.cpp.s

    rectangle.obj: rectangle.cpp.obj

     .PHONY : rectangle.obj

      # target to build an object file
      rectangle.cpp.obj:
       $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
 CMakeFiles/A3.dir/rectangle.cpp.obj
      .PHONY : rectangle.cpp.obj

      rectangle.i: rectangle.cpp.i

      .PHONY : rectangle.i

        # target to preprocess a source file
        rectangle.cpp.i:
             $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
 CMakeFiles/A3.dir/rectangle.cpp.i
          .PHONY : rectangle.cpp.i

       rectangle.s: rectangle.cpp.s

         .PHONY : rectangle.s

       # target to generate assembly for a file
       rectangle.cpp.s:
            $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
        CMakeFiles/A3.dir/rectangle.cpp.s
       .PHONY : rectangle.cpp.s

       shape.obj: shape.cpp.obj

       .PHONY : shape.obj

        # target to build an object file
          shape.cpp.obj:
         $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
  CMakeFiles/A3.dir/shape.cpp.obj
        .PHONY : shape.cpp.obj

            shape.i: shape.cpp.i

          .PHONY : shape.i

         # target to preprocess a source file
         shape.cpp.i:
         $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
         CMakeFiles/A3.dir/shape.cpp.i
         .PHONY : shape.cpp.i

          shape.s: shape.cpp.s

         .PHONY : shape.s

        # target to generate assembly for a file
        shape.cpp.s:
          $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles\A3.dir\build.make 
  CMakeFiles/A3.dir/shape.cpp.s
         .PHONY : shape.cpp.s

          # Help Target
         help:
               @echo The following are some of the valid targets for this 
   Makefile:
                @echo ... all (the default if no target is provided)
                 @echo ... clean
                @echo ... depend
                @echo ... rebuild_cache
                @echo ... A3
                @echo ... edit_cache
                @echo ... CompositeShape.obj
                @echo ... CompositeShape.i
                @echo ... CompositeShape.s
                @echo ... circle.obj
                @echo ... circle.i
                @echo ... circle.s
                @echo ... main.obj
                @echo ... main.i
                @echo ... main.s
                @echo ... rectangle.obj
                @echo ... rectangle.i
                @echo ... rectangle.s
                 @echo ... shape.obj
                 @echo ... shape.i
                 @echo ... shape.s
           .PHONY : help
```

#=============================================================================
              # Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

```
      # Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
    # No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
  # because they might be regenerated.
  cmake_check_build_system:
     $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake
  .PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

При этом CODE::Blocs говорит об ошибке в этом месте:

```
   $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake
```

Comment: Попробуйте создать [mcve]. Ковыряться в простынях желающих мало.

Comment: Как пишет так и есть. У вас  с форматом, что-то. После А3:... нет табулатора в следующей строчке